# Assign multiple variable from multiple rows in a select statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a list returning from select statement.

For example

```
select type, id
from userlist
```

returns:

```
type id
1    102
2    125
3    156
```

Now I want to assign variable values based on the type. Is it possible in single statement?

Like

```
SELECT
    case when type = 1 then @frontenduser = id 
         when type = 2 then @backenduser = id 
         when type = 3 then @newuser = id 
    end
FROM 
    (SELECT type, id
     FROM userlist) AS tbl1
```

Comment: In your example you return multiple rows. You can't put multiple rows in a single variable, because the system can't know which one you want to have at the end of the statement.

Comment: Are you trying to build a dynamic where clause based on the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternative to `pivot`:

```
select
    @frontenduser = case type when 1 then id else @frontenduser end,
    @backenduser = case type when 2 then id else @backenduser end,
    @newuser = case type when 3 then id else @newuser end
from userlist
```

or the same, using `iif` operator (if you use SqlServer 2012 or later):

```
select
    @frontenduser = iif(type = 1, id, @frontenduser),
    @backenduser = iif(type = 2, id, @backenduser),
    @newuser = iif(type = 3, id, @newuser)
from userlist
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I tried running the same query and I found that out of all , only one variable gets assigned. Can you please check it once

Comment: @Shru, please see SQL Fiddle sample ([link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c9e8/2)), showing that all variables assigned, I can't reproduce problem.

Comment: Thank you .. I got it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can if you pivot the table.

```
select
   @frontenduser = [1],
   @backenduser = [2],
   @newuser = [3]
from
(
    select [type], id
    from userlist
) As tbl
PIVOT
(
   MAX(id)
   FOR [type] IN([1],[2],[3])
) As pivotTable
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that.  What you can do is restrict the query by type.  For example, `WHERE type = 1` and have one query for each type in your table.  Or you could send the results to a varchar and parse it later.

With that being said, the *best* course of action would be to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your table.  Then you wouldn't have to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting into a variable is only good for a single result. The data is already identifying which users are in different types i.e. frontenduser/backenduser/newuser so if you want to use this information to do something, you will need to do something else!

For instance, if you want to 'do something' for each type of user you could use a cursor (I personally don't like them but you can...).

In Pseudo code:

```
Fill a cursor with users

For each user in the cursor
Begin
    If the user is of type 1 Then do something
    If the user is of type 2 Then do something else
End
```

etc...